# How to retain the scientfic format of the numbers while knitting to pdf in rstudio?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc

The below two code chunks reflects the same output in the R console. But when knit to pdf,it gives me different output. Why?

````
```{r}
x = 2.22e-16
x
```

```{r}
as.data.frame(x)
```
````

Output when knitting to pdf:

[image]

You can see that, in the data frame, it shows `0` instead of `2.22e-16`.

How to correct this?

Note: I use `printr` package for the nice dataframe and matrix outputs.
setting `options(digits = 17)`  solved the problem but it doesnot seems to be a good solution since it affects all the other chunks if I set it globally.

Comment: formatC(x, digits=2, format="e")